# Node.js: Маршрутизация в другое приложение?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер

Доброе время сток!

Как мне организовать маршрутизации? У меня есть корень, в котором есть несколько приложений, как мне динамически выводить их список, открывать конкретное приложение при разных запросах.

Например:

```
IP/chat - приложение 1
IP/site - приложение 2
IP/API - приложение 3
```

Структура:

```
папка приложений
--- приложение 1
--- приложение 2
--- приложение 3
```

Если написать app.get(и путь), то слушая на 80 порту у второго app будет ошибка

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000

Comment: Скорее всего наилучшим решением будет раскидать приложения по разным портам, и перед ними поставить nginx, который в зависимости от url будет проксировать запросы на нужное приложение.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая схема:

```
var chat = require('./chat/index');
var chat = require('./site/index');
var api = require('./api/index');
app
    .use('/chat', chat)
    .use('/site', site)
    .use('/api', api)
```

chat/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/rooms', function (req, res) {
    res.render('./chat/views/rooms.html');
});
```

а динамически выводить - закиньте в конфиг список приложений, из него и в роутер их засовываете и рендерьте на главной

Comment: ну так выходит нужно логику всю держать корне. Как ее переместить в chat/index.js?

Comment: @VINET, в корне вы держите главный роутер, всю логику пишите в чате, в чем проблема?